# Mysql JOIN table and update 2 columns information

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

```
//user
id  name
1   A
2   B
3   C

//mail
send   receive  message
1      2
3      2
2      1

//result
send   receive  message
A      B
C      B
B      A
```

I have 2 tables `user` and `mail`

`user` table stores `name`, `mail` table stores `id` for send and receive

I need to merge `user` table with `mail`

`send` & `receive` column will display name from `user` table id match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the `mail` table with the `users` table twice - once to get the name of the sender and once to get the name of the receiver:

```
SELECT s.name, r.name, m.message
FROM   mail m
JOIN   users s ON m.send = s.id
JOIN   users r ON m.recieve = r.id
```